# Corda - question for flow have multi state

Tags: corda

I have 2 states : invoice state keep detail of invoice such as invoice no , amount , vat , payment batch (reference to payment state) etc. and payment state keep detail of payment such as payment batch , items of invoice. What's the best practices to implement flow when invoice paid ?

1. create updatePaymentFlow for update status to "PAID" in payment state and create updateInoviceFlow for update status to "PAID" in invoice state and then loop of all invoice in payment batch to call updateInoviceFlow.
2. create only flow updatePaymentAndInvoiceFlow for update both payment state and invoice state.

If there is an example that would be great.

[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs3cX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the picture I understand that a Payment is dependent on Invoice state, and an Invoice state will have its own status - PAID/UNPAID, and Payment state will have its own status field - PAID/UNPAID. Payment state status will be PAID once all the invoice's have PAID status. I think what is the best way to implement this scenario is what your question is.

I would say have Invoice state as a [StatePointer](https://www.corda.net/blog/linking-corda-states-using-statepointer/) in your Payment state. In this way you can have a flow which will take care of updating the Invoice status. And you can have other flow which takes care of updating your Payment status. In this way, invoice status can be updated independently of Payment. Also having referencing the invoice as StatePointer(Linear Pointer) will always give you the latest updated state in Payment.